# Trigger div on pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to set the scroll of my page to a certain div. Kindly let me know how can i do that. Following is my code in which each each option in li moves to certain div . I tried this         $("#header3").click(); in doucument.ready function but it didnot work.

Kindly help!

```
<ul id="navigation">

            <LI><A class="home selected-lice"href="#header">Home</A></LI>


            <LI><A  href="#header4">Partners</A></LI>

                <LI><A class="about" href="#header5">About Us</A></LI>

            <LI><A class="contact" href="#header6">Contact Us</A></LI>


        </ul><!-- end of #navigation -->
```

Comment: You dont have any element with id `header1` in your markup. You can use `$('#navigation li a:first').click()` or simply `$('a.home').click()`

Comment: yeah i mistakenly write header1 an edit it now but still no luck :(

Comment: If you want it to move it to `#header3` then you have to do `$('a.why').click()` as `why` is the class of that anchor tag.

Comment: Thanks for the help i out `$(document).ready(function() {
 
 
$('a.why').click();
        alert('hi');


 });` in my piece of code but it didnot do the trick and the scroll doesnot go to certain div but it alert 'hi' ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Alternatively* you can use this to scroll to *specific* element on page load with *animation*:

```
$(function(){
   $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#header1").offset().top });
});
```

Comment: WOW it worked thanks alot bhai. I am very much great full to you.

Comment: bhai one last question can i send the request to load certain div with a url only something like abc.com/#header1  cause the approach i am using i have to make 5 separate files for my task and update all of them if it can be done by including any piece of code in my one file then it'll be best for me

Comment: @softgenic: What do you mean exactly by `load certain div`. You want specific div element to be loaded in current page or when you visit such url, it should automatically scroll to it ?

Comment: @softgenic: Or better you might want to ask a separate question for it to get more answers so that others could also answer if i am not available :)

Comment: when I visit such url, it should automatically scroll to it. This approach would be best for me (cause my current solution is worst case)

Comment: Kindly bhai answer it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071330/scroll-to-certain-div-when-when-i-visit-url

Answer (score 0):

check this link:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

or try to overwrite the usual anchor behavior with some scrolling. Like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('a[href^=#]').click(function(e){
    var name = $(this).attr('href').substr(1);
    var pos = $('a[name='+name+']').offset();
    $('body').animate({ scrollTop: pos.top });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: i want to load certain div on page load